# What does "spaced generously at 75" mean?

Tags: typography, terminology, units

I'm reading an article on typography and it is suggested at one point that a certain heading should have "Small Caps, spaced generously at 75".

What does that number, 75, represent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would assume tracking (or letter spacing).

[image]

In Adobe software that is measured as 1/1000 of an em (so "75" is 0.075 em). In QuarkXPress it is measured as 1/200 of an em (so "75" is 0.375 em) and there are probably other variations (you can set CSS `letter-spacing` in whatever unit you like, for example)... So without knowing the context in which it is being talked about that number is a bit ambiguous.

Comment: It seems you are right and it would be not be QarkXPress software as .375em would be far too large.

Comment: Is this the article you're talking about: http://retinart.net/typography/typographicscale/ (that was the only result searching for the line you quoted) ? ...if so they mention InDesign so that would be it